# Decrypt hex string with python

Tags: python, string, encryption, hex, aes

I encrypted a String with Java (on Android) and I get 'A14E71A6F4E8D8E465C3C302C2A96BD2' as a byte array.

I now want to encrypt it with python, but it doesn't work:

```
cipher = 'A14E71A6F4E8D8E465C3C302C2A96BD2'
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
print aes.decrypt(cipher)
```

I already searched the internet, but didn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How was it encrypted originally? Was it with AES? Do you have the same key? You also need to decode the base64 before decrypting

Comment: If you are wondering why you have so many downvotes on your question please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What about the iv, it is the same? Does Python AES expect hexadecimal encoded input encryption?

Comment: On Android I use "Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")". It returns a byte-array which I send as a SMS to a Raspi on which the python script runs.

I use the same iv in python as I used in on Android.

Comment: @TobiasKohlhauf Does Python AES expect hexadecimal encoded input encryption ordoes it need to be decoded to binary?

Comment: The python documentation says "byte string". Unfortunately I'm not that used to python and honestly I have some troubles with python not being strongly typed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2 you can decode the hex string using [`str.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

cipher = 'A14E71A6F4E8D8E465C3C302C2A96BD2'
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
print aes.decrypt(cipher.decode('hex'))
```

If everything else is in place (iv, key, encryption mode) this might work.

If you want this to work in both Python 2 and Python 3 then you can use [`binascii.unhexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to decode the hex encoded string:

```
from binascii import unhexlify

cipher = unhexlify(b'A14E71A6F4E8D8E465C3C302C2A96BD2')
```

Comment: Thank you! The unhexlify version worked in my case! (:

Answer (score 0):

It may not be enough, you have not said how this was encrypted, but at the least you need to hex decode this before you decrypt.

```
cipherData = binascii.unhexlify(cipher)
...
print aes.decrypt(cipherData)
```

Comment: In java I use "Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")".
Hope that helps.

If I use the base64 decoder I get an error: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

Comment: Yes, the output of the java encryption function is hex. But I don't know how to decrypt that hex-String in python.

Comment: My bad, yes I glanced at the data and thought base64, hex it is.